# new class in included files

Tags: php, oop, include

I have some classes, and that classes are included in `index.php` file , like :

```
<?php
 include("./includes/user.class.php");
 include("./includes/anotherclass.class.php");
?>
```

then I have :

```
  $layout = new layout();
  $layout->sampleMethod;
```

then in the body i have :

```
include("pages/samplePage.php");
```

then in that `samplePage.php`

i have to create `new layout()` again to use class functions, is there a way to use `$layout->method` in included file without create another object?

**more code:**

Layout class :

```
public function mkLayout()
  {
    include("pages/page.php");
  }
public function getPageUrl()
  {
    echo "PAGE URL";
  }
```

some of index.php :

```
<?php
  require_once("includes/layout.class.php");

  $layout = new layout();
  $layout->mkLayout();
?>
```

some of samplePage.php

```
  <?php
    $layout->getPageUrl();
   ?>
```

the samplePage.php returns :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getPageUrl() on a non-object in
```

Comment: If you are including `samplePage.php` from the inside of the function, you can just use `$this` I think. But I'm not sure.

Comment: You include structure isn't great, you want to be including classes or function libraries in all but the one executing script, pretty much.  Which means that in general you should be using `require_once` library includes instead of just `include`.

Comment: oh it already was require_once ) , but thanks for advice

Comment: where does `samplePage.php` get included?

Comment: This is what I got when testing: http://codepad.org/4tgycVAR

Comment: @afuzzy inside the `layout` object.

Comment: inside layout class .  $layout->mkLayout(); >>> include($page[full_address]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `$layout` in your included page, it should be working normally, assuming of course you declared `$layout = new layout();` before you included `samplePage.php`.

If it doesn't work for you, try `var_dump()`ing it in your included page and see what you get there. Though it should be working as you are asking.

## Edit!

After digging a little I found that wherever the file is included it inherits the scope of the function/method that used it, so use

```
global $layout;
```

Before you try to use methods and it should be working fine.

**[Manual Entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)**:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

Useful links:

- **[Variable Scope - PHP Manual](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)**

Comment: var_dump() returns null value. how it works : index.php includes classes and creates object ($layout = new layout();), then layout class includes page ( page/samplepage.php ), then i want in samplePage.php file to use $layout object methods but i don't want to create new object for each page

Comment: It should be working as you describe it, I'll do some testing myself and see.

Comment: I tested and confirmed your problem, though I'm stumped. Awesome question. Let's see if no one can answer it, and I'll put up a bounty

Comment: @John found it. variable scope

Comment: Liberally using `global` isn't the greatest [idea](http://tjhunt.blogspot.com/2009/04/php-global-variables-are-not.html)

Comment: Perhaps, but it does the job here, and that's kinda it's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, except you want to include the file that contains the previous instantiation of the layout class.

Answer (score 0):

Going off what you have posted, if this is how your code looks:

```
<?php
    include("./includes/user.class.php");
    include("./includes/anotherclass.class.php");

    $layout = new layout();
    $layout->sampleMethod;

    include("pages/samplePage.php");
?>
```

`$layout` should already be declared in your `pages/samplePage.php`.  Try doing `var_dump($layout)` in `pages/samplePage.php` and you'll see that it is already defined.

---

Why not just have a layout member inside of your class?

Comment: it returns null value. i just want to use $layout->method in included page without creating new object. structure : index.php includes classes and creates object ($layout = new layout();), then layout class includes page ( page/samplepage.php ), then i want in samplePage.php file to use $layout object methods but i don't want to create new object for each page

Comment: Post more of your code, with what you have provided it should be defined.  Are you trying to access your $layout inside of another class?

Comment: The include is called from the layout class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not really striving for object orientation in this example. Consider just using plain functions without classes.